# Angular usage of self and setting up a basic angular app

Tags: angularjs

I am reading through some of the documentation and a thinkster tutorial. Here is some code:

My controller with a dependency on messages factory:

```
angular.module('app').controller('PostCtrl', function (messages){
  var self = this;

  self.newMessage = 'Hello World!';

  self.addMessage = function(message){
    messages.add(message);
    self.newMessage = '';
  };
});
```

My simple form html:

```
</div>
<div ng-controller="PostCtrl as post">
  <form ng-submit="post.addMessage(post.newMessage)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.newMessage">
    <button type="submit">Add Message</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

my messages factory:

```
angular.module('app').factory('messages', function(){
  var messages = {};

  messages.list = [];

  messages.add = function(message){
    messages.list.push({id: messages.list.length, text: message});
  };

  return messages;
});
```

My questions:
1) In the controller, what does messages refer to on the line:

```
messages.add(message);
```

Is the messages referring to the factory name or the

```
var messages
```

in the factory?

2) Why do we go through the trouble of defining self in the controller?

Comment: `messages` is referring to the factory itself, not `var messages = {};`.  `messages.add(message);` is calling the `add` function on the `messages` factory. I haven't used the `var self = this;` before so I can't really answer that part. I just use `$scope`

Comment: `var self = this` helps fix scope problems that may pop up in a complex application. Using `self` instead of `this` ensures that whenever `self` is invoked, it always refers to the thing at top-most scope (the AngularJS module).

Comment: hmmm, I still am a tad confused why this and self would differ from inside this controller?